# Get text with html tags from main DIV by jquery?

Tags: jquery, text

How to get text with html tags, but only from main DIV? Not form other DIVS.

Here is example, but there is some problem, becouse text is without html tag <**br** />

[**jsFiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ynternet/F6AeM/)

HTML

```
<div id='parent'>
    this text is <br />for parent

   <div id='child-parent'> 
     this text if for child-parent  
       <div id='child'>
        and this text is for child.   
       </div>   
   </div>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
alert($('#parent').clone().children().remove().end().html());
```

Comment: `$.text()` returns a string of the content without tags.

Comment: @Broxzier -- He wants those tags.

Comment: Can you explain what you expect to return from this example?

Comment: But I want to return string with tags.

Comment: I expect  "this text is <**br** />for parent"

Comment: `alert($('#parent').find(':not(br)').remove().end().html());`

Comment: Thank you, it works, but... "br" was just an example. I need tags and text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated your fiddle and used a different tactic to remove the last element

http://jsfiddle.net/F6AeM/1/

```
var parent = $('#parent').clone();
$(parent).find('#child-parent').remove();
alert($(parent).html());
```

Not sure why this works, but yours doesn't, but here you go.

Comment: thank you,  it works fine :)... but is there solution if those IDs will be created dinamicaly, and if there will be more DIVs to remove ? that is the reason, why I use "**.clone().children().remove().end().html()**"

Comment: If it's always divs, you can change the selector to "div".  Like in this fiddle.  http://jsfiddle.net/F6AeM/4/  This will remove every div not just the last one.

Answer (score 1):

*Assuming `child-parent` and `child` will always have an `id`*

```
var clone = $('#parent').clone();
clone.children().filter(function () {
    return $(this).is('[id]');
}).remove();

console.log(clone.html());
```

Demo `--->` http://jsfiddle.net/F6AeM/5/

Comment: That doesn't really work, it's not returning the BR tag, it's just outputting a newline, which is the nodeValue of the middle node.

Comment: Thanks, it works fine. Interesting and simple solution. If I want to use other tags for text formating like this - http://jsfiddle.net/ynternet/F6AeM/6/ ?

Comment: Thank you, every solution was helpfull to me. Finaly I changed concept of my original script. Thank you for help... I must save your both scripts, becous they were interesting to me :)